# How I check my one column value is present in another column

Tags: python, pyspark

I have one SQL dataframe which having three columns

```
port    test1        test2
123     apple        ramesh eat apple
436     banana       banana is not a friute
467     cat 
78      tiger        cat is pet
```

And I want to find test1 column value is present in test2 column value.And I want output like this

```
port test1  test2                        check
123  apple  ramesh eat apple               1
436  banana banana is not a fruit          1
467  cat                                   0
78   tiger  cat is pet                     0
```

Comment: Hi Vishwajeet nice question. I executed @cph_sto code and it is working as expected. Just want to know , why exactly you are using pyspark here.

Comment: It is my project requirement that why i am using this. I want to execute hive query faster.Is there any alternative of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`contains`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.contains) function to solve this problem. It's pretty straight forward.

```
df = df.withColumn('check',when(col('test2').contains(col('test1')),1).otherwise(0))
df.show(truncate=False)

+----+------+---------------------+-----+
|port|test1 |test2                |check|
+----+------+---------------------+-----+
|123 |apple |ramesh eat apple     |1    |
|436 |banana|banana is not a fruit|1    |
|467 |cat   |null                 |0    |
|78  |tiger |cat is pet           |0    |
+----+------+---------------------+-----+
```

Comment: the **contains** is not work for all the word.can you give more efficient way to do same thing.

Comment: __1st column__).    **rsh protocol - used to execute non-interactive 
                  commandline commands on a remote system and see the screen return**   __2nd column__). **SYSLOG**...we are performing the contain on these 2 column  so the result we get is 1....

Comment: 1st and 2nd column or 2nd and 3rd column? We are not doing any test on 1st column... clarify

Comment: in test1 i have value **rsh protocol - used to execute non-interactive commandline commands on a remote system and see the screen return** AND in test2 **SYSLOG** and it giving me 1 in check column.Although test1 is not in test2.

Comment: Ok, I have just checked it in my code. I get `0`. I don't know as to why are you getting `1`! I am on Spark `2.4`. I hereby confirm that `.contains()` works and there is no problem with it.

Comment: their was a issue of case senstive letter..how to accept both uppercase and lowercase letter

Comment: You can convert both to, let's say, `lower` case while doing `when()` operation. That should make the `case` redundant. Do the following change -  `lower(col('test2'))` & `lower(col('test2'))` and import the function `lower()`. That's all. Good Bye

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using the sql syntax :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn(
    "check",
    F.expr("case when test2 like concat('%', test1, '%') then 1 else 0 end")
).show()
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use

```
df['check'] = df.apply(lambda row: int(row.test1 in row.test2), axis = 1)
```

Comment: I have SQL dataframe not a pandas dataframe

Comment: my bad didn't notice